# Window without WindowStyle and maximized window state hides the taskbar

Tags: .net, wpf, taskbar, windowstate

WPF application with WindowState Maximized and WindowStyle None hides the taskbar. Since my application runs on a Customer Wrapper Application which has its own taskbar and Windows Start button equivalent, i need to ensure that my application doesnt hide the taskbar in maximized mode. I believe its a behavior different from what i have seen in Winforms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same issue. The best approach is to handle this with API Calls. This code worked great for me.

[Taskbar with Window Maximized and WindowState to None in WPF](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/09/taskbar-with-window-maximized-and.html)

Comment: the solution works perfect in my Virtual machine running a Windows XP, but on the Custom Shell it behaves weird. And to my surprise there are different versions of the custom Shell. Waiting for the test environment with latest Custom Shell to make my application conform to its standards! Thanks Agustin!

Comment: I'm unclear on implementation since the download link for his source is dead but simply changing the window width/height doesn't work for me. The behavior isn't what I wanted.